# BAD_ACCESS error when trying to set value of unique pointer boolean array

Tags: c++, syntax, unique-ptr

I am not sure if this is a syntax issue but I have tried messing with the declarations and can't seem to shake the error. Here are my private member variables in the header file.

```
   class PrimeGenerator

{
   private:

          unique_ptr<bool[]> sequence;

          int length;
```

These declarations drew a BAD_ALLOCATION error. Is my syntax incorrect? How do I declare the members of the unique_ptr array?

```
sequence[0] = 0;
sequence[1] = 0;
sequence[2] = 1;
```

Comment: Bad C++ syntax results in a compiation error. If your program compiled, its syntax is valid C++. But, as you've discovered, just because your program compiles doesn't mean that it's correct. You have a bug in your code. Unfortunately, there is insufficient information given to indicate what the bug is. You need to visit stackoverflow.com's [help], then [edit] your question, and provide a [mcve].

Comment: Your *unique_ptr* isn't pointing at anything because you have not given it a value, it's empty. Try `unique_ptr<bool[]> sequence{new bool[3]};` and maybe look for a tutorial on using smart pointers?

Comment: You have a unique pointer object that, if appropriately initialized or assigned, *can* point to an array of `bool`. Whether you actually did that is left to our imagination, since this isn't a [mcve] . If you don't have something in your code that looks something like `sequence = std::make_unique<bool[]>(size);`, where `size` is a previously determine value, then you didn't allocate an array and any referencing through `sequence` will invoke undefined behavior.

Comment: Unrelated: consider using a `std::vector` for this. I can't promise it'll be faster, but it will be easier.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that in your code  `unique_ptr<bool[]> sequence;` does not have any value to point into.

```
unique_ptr<bool[]> sequence{new bool[3]};
```

You can try with the above code. Also as mentioned, a smart pointer is a class that wraps a 'raw' (or 'bare') C++ pointer, to manage the lifetime of the object being pointed to.
With raw pointers, the programmer has to explicitly destroy the object when it is no longer useful. A smart pointer by comparison defines a policy as to when the object is destroyed. You still have to create the object, but you no longer have to worry about destroying it.